# Can't login to remote SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a little app to test connection to a remote SQL server using the following code:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder bu = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        bu.DataSource = @"<server>";
        bu.InitialCatalog = "<database>";
        bu.IntegratedSecurity = false; 
        bu.UserID = "<user id>";
        bu.Password = "<password>";

        myConnection.ConnectionString = bu.ConnectionString;

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

I am getting the unhelpful message "login failed for user...". I can login using that user on the server itself so the credentials are correct. I have also set the database to accept remote logins. I can ping back and forth to the server.

Is there a way to further test this to try and diagnose the problem?

Comment: Turn off the firewall on both machines and see if that is the issue.

Comment: set IntegratedSecurity = true

Comment: I set that to true and it overrides the user ID and password I set in the code and uses my windows login credentials. I want to use an SQL login.

Comment: Hard to debug without being there. Missing the server instance maybe? Was the windows login successful? Try changing the initialcatalog value and see if the error changes.

Comment: I think I have it figured out. For the data source I was using the AWS server IP. But I have to use the SQL Server name. How does it know that it's on that server though? Sorry, I am a noob when it comes to networking and servers and such like.